# How does one know a DLL is actually safe to use?

Tags: dll, malware-detection

I've downloaded a certain DLL from the web and then uploaded it to Jotti's virus scan. All of those engines reported **Found nothing**. Nothing.

Can there still be some sort of security issue with this file or am I pretty safe that this file's ok?

What else should I consider to check its *bad intentions*?

> Yes it's a patch for some original DLL. SLL is a compiled non-managed code. It differs from the original in a bit more than 2k bytes. I thought of decompiling it and compare source code of both to see differences, but since it's unmanaged DLL I'm pretty much done.

Comment: You either trust the source or you don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unknown source so nothing to base my trust on. I'd like to go with more than just *guts* or *trust*. I'd like a more specific test.

Comment: Run it and see what happens to your computer, bank account, and children.

Comment: Ha ha. Very funny. You should go into comedy. 

Comment: A bunch of virus scanners found nothing, which means that it doesn't contain a known problem.  So you're looking for something that finds unknown problems?

Comment: @fixer1234 you're right. If those didn't find anything, not even a false positive, then there are only two options. 1. File is fine 2. File has a completely new virus with some completely new way of execution...

Comment: @fixer1234 I'd say that, #2 has a higher probability. **Can you please make your comment an answer** so I can accept it as the best possible answer to this rather vague question. Thanks.

Comment: I relinquish all rights to my comment.  Feel free to use it if you want to create your own answer. :-)